# Selector multiple, que debe comprobar si el valor existe en una tabla, y marcarlo como "selected"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo un multi-select que he implementado con "bootstrap-multiselector",

La cosa es que yo printo los "option" mediante un loop que coje los datos desde una tabla de "oficinas"

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="zonas-interes[]" multiple data-live-search="true"> 
    @foreach($oficinas as $oficina)
        <option value="{{$oficina->id}}" >{{$oficina->nombre}}</option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
```

Visualmente es algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funciona correctamente, la cosa es que yo tengo una tabla dónde hay una relacion de "1 pedido puede tener varias zonas de interes" "en esa tabla guardo el pedido id y la oficina_id

La cosa es que yo quiero es en la vista de editar, que salgan seleccionadas las opciones "mediante un selected", si el id de la tabla zonas_interes_oficina ( que lo puedo obtener desde $pedido->zonas_interes, y posteriormente con $pedido->zonas_interes->oficina_id sacaría la id, pero el problema es que hay varios valores!, es un array lo que saca, y lo he intentado de estas formas pero no me deja )

```
@foreach($oficinas as $oficina)                                                                        
    @foreach($pedido->zonas_interes as $zona)                                                                    
        @if($oficina->id == $zona->oficina_id)                                                                    
            <option value="{{$oficina->id}}" selected>{{$oficina->nombre}}</option>                                                                          
             @continue
         @else
             <option value="{{$oficina->id}}">{{$oficina->nombre}}</option>    
         @endif                                                           
      @endforeach
  @endforeach
```

Se ven las opciones, pero se duplican de todas formas, y yo quiero que si los valores coinciden, se seleccione, y pase a la siguiente iteraccion, de esta forma creo que esta iterando mal "por eso el @continue"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que algo me falla al LOOP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta ha sido hacerlo de esta forma:

```
@foreach($oficinas as $oficina)
     <?php $exists = 0;?>
         @foreach($pedido->zonas_interes as $zona)
             @if($oficina->id == $zona->oficina_id)
                 <?php $exists = 1;?>
             @endif
@endforeach
<option value="{{$oficina->id}}" {{$exists?'selected':''}}>{{$oficina->nombre}}</option>  
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que se repiten porque empezas recorriendo oficinas y cada vez que no coincide *$oficina->id == $zona->oficina_id* te imprime la oficina sin el selected y eso lo hace por cada pedido, no estoy seguro de como deberías armarlo, si en la vista o en el controlador pero te comento la lógica que creo funcionaría, lo haría con una bandera true o false, o sea:

```
foreach($oficinas as $oficina)                                                                        
    $ofi_selected = false;
    foreach($pedido->zonas_interes as $zona)                                                                    
        if($oficina->id == $zona->oficina_id)                                                                    
            <option value="{{$oficina->id}}" selected>{{$oficina->nombre}}</option>                                                                          
             $ofi_selected = true;
             @break;
        endif                                                           
    endforeach
    if($ofi_selected==false){
           <option value="{{$oficina->id}}">{{$oficina->nombre}}</option>    
    }
endforeach
```

Esta lógica imprime la oficina sólo una vez si no la encuentra en los pedidos, obviamente esto así no funciona porque no podés manejar una variable de esa forma en la vista, pero por ahí debe ir la solución.

Comment: gracias, ya lo he resuelto! :)

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo esta solución ya que es la que yo uso en mis proyectos y siempre me funciona, con esto evito hacer un foreach dentro de un foreach.

```php
<select class="selectpicker" name="zonas-interes[]" multiple data-live-search="true"> 
    @foreach($oficinas as $oficina)
        @if( !empty($zonasinteres->oficina->find($oficina->id)->id) )
            <option
            {{ $zonasinteres->oficina->find($oficina->id)->id == $oficina->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}
            value="{{ $oficina->id }}">
                {{ $oficina->nombre }}
            </option>
        @else
            <option value="{{ $oficina->id }}">{{ $oficina->nombre }}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
 </select>
```